# Match button height based on image aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a group of 16x9 images that are set to a percentage width (20%) with an add button thrown into the mix. I need the height of the add button to equal that of the images. I've tried setting the "height" of the button using `padding-top` and I've set it to 11.25% which is 9/16 of 20%.

This almost works in Chrome but in the example, when you resize the window (in fullscreen), sub-pixel rendering kicks in and renders a height greater for the button than the image resulting in wrapping issues.

Is there a better way of achieving this using flexbox perhaps? one that will work without sub-pixel rendering issues?

```css
.imageSection {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imageSection > img,
.imageSection > button {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imageSection > button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 11.25%; /* (20 / 16) * 9 */
  position: relative;
  background: #bd2a72;
  color: #fff;
}

.imageSection > button::after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 14px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageSection">
  <button></button>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```css
.imageSection {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.imageSection > img,
.imageSection > button {
  width: 20%;  
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  height:100%;
}

.imageSection > button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: #bd2a72;
  color: #fff;
  height:inherit;
}

.imageSection > button::after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 14px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageSection">
  <button></button>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" />
</div>
```